# kdb/Q How to store and return multiple values in a function?

Tags: list, kdb

I have a question about returning one of two lists with the more optimal metric.

My function takes in a list of numbers. It then changes one of those numbers, and compares which list has the highest value when the contents of each list are added up.

I would like it to then return the list with the higher metric AND the metric.

For example:

```
original_list = [1 2 3]

def my_function:{[original_list]
    # create a new list, changing just one value
    new_list = change_one_number[original_list]

    # generate the metrics for both lists
    original_metric = calculate_metric[original_list]
    new_metric = calculate_metric[new_list]

    #if statement here
    ?[new_metric >= original_metric; new_list; original_list]}
                                     ^         ^
                                     #these outputs are just the list though
```

I'm wondering how I can return the list with the higher metric and the metric, is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can just return a list consisting of two elements, your modified list and the original list, or anything really.

```
f:{[originalList]
  newList:modify[originalList];
  :(originalList;newList);
}
```

basically you're returning a list of list, where the first list is your original and the second list is your new list.